# A puzzle with grids and lines

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image: An image showing various 4x5 grids being connected by lines into a big map. Some lines lead to diamonds with a number from 1-7, and some of the grids have been redacted and instead shows the letter A-G.]

**What would be an appropriate song to listen to after solving this puzzle?**

**EDIT 1 [June 14, 2022]**

- Fixed the two top left grids being coloured incorrectly
- Fixed one of the 6 missing a connection

Comment: The operator labelled 6 on the right has 2 inputs whereas the one on the left has at most 1 input. Is this correct?

Comment: No, of course not. That has been fixed.

Comment: The row of not equals statements linked together at the bottom is not intended to mean that none of them are equal, right? I.e. 2 cannot equal 1 or 3, but could equal one or more others as long as the entire statement is true, such as 4 and 6.

Comment: @JLee Yes, all 7 diamonds are distinct.

Comment: Please double-check the grid at the bottom under the 7. I think rows 3 and 4 should be all red instead of all white.

Comment: @JLee No, it is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Just continuing on from SQLnoob's answer since they're incredibly close,

> the images spell out "JS**a**BLv4" short for Just shapes and beats lvl 4, which is titled `LOGIC GATEKEEPER`

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> The black diamonds appear to be Boolean operations that act on the grids. We are given that 1 is NOT (which solves F), 6 is NOR, and 7 is XOR. Since C has no arrows pointing into it, 3 must be reversible, and if all 7 diamonds represent distinct operations then 3 must be XNOR.

> This allows us to solve D, B, C, and G in one fell swoop, and also show that 5 is NAND.
>  [image]

Here's where everything falls apart:

> Look at the top 4 and the 2, and consider the function (x4y)2z. If 2 and 4 are both functions like 1, 3, 5, 6, and 7, then this composition is also a function. However, the third and fifth rows of the second column have identical input triplets (011) and opposite outputs, and broadening our possible scope of functions (for example, allowing 4 to flip its left input vertically and its right output horizontally, which is the only way to introduce flips to 4 so all of this checks out) destroys our ability to do deductions.

Comment: Yep, I've made a mistake in labeling some of the grids at the top. The image has now been updated. Although, from your image, I can also see discrepensies that is not caused by the incorrect grids as well.

Answer (score 4):

The seven black diamonds are

> [logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Truth_tables), as follows:
>
> 1 = NOT
>  2 = OR
>  3 = XOR
>  4 = AND
>  5 = NOR
>  6 = NAND
>  7 = XNOR

When applied to the images,

> treating a white square as 1 and a red square as 0, we get the following for the missing images A-G:
>  [image: 2]
>  which appears to spell out JSoBLv4 (?).

But I don't know what song that is referring to.

Comment: Strange how only 1 of the 7 logic gates match mine but answer is the exact same except for c

Comment: Interesting, what do you have for C? Because that's the only one that isn't obvious (to me) what it's supposed to represent.